# count item from relation table in codeigniter 3

Tags: database, codeigniter, relation

I want to count each post inside a category in codeigniter 3
My model now is:

```
public function get_category()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    return $query->result_array();
}


public function getPostByCategory($id)
{       
    $query= $this->db->select("*")
                                ->from('post')
                                ->join('category','category.id = post.category_id')
                                ->where('post.category_id',$id)
                                ->get();

    return $query->result_array();      
}
```

I'm trying to print out the "archive" menu in view, in my controller

```
$data['category'] = $this->category_model->get_category();
```

but this print out all category title, including the empty ones. How can i print only category with posts?

Comment: Have you tried `$data['category'] = $this->category_model->getPostByCategory($id);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the category and join it with posts and then get all categories that are not null and then group it to see unique values. You can try this:

```
$this->db->select("category.id, category.title")
        ->from('category')
        ->join('post','category.id = post.category_id')
        ->where(array('post.category_id !=' => NULL, 'category.id !=' => NULL))
        ->group_by(array("category.id", "category.title"))
        ->get();
```

Let me know if you encountered any errors. Thanks!